# Error:(7, 0) Could not get unknown property 'ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION' for project ':vitamio' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: android, sdk, live-streaming, vitamio

When I tried to import the module of vitamio sdk this error occur

```
Error:(7, 0) Could not get unknown property 'ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION' for project ':vitamio' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

This is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

dependencies {
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION)
    buildToolsVersion project.ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION)
        targetSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }

    }

}
```

I want to have an online live streaming using vitamio sdk because the libvlc sdk have a delay on the live steeam videos

Comment: can you try adding something like compile 'me.neavo:vitamio:4.2.2' inside dependencies?

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: Have you resolved this? I'm having the same issue